# problems with shapefile output - fiona

Tags: shapely, fiona, pysal

I'm using Fiona to write a shapefile containing geometries of US Census congressional districts and census tracts with some computed attributes. Unfortunately, my file is being outputted blank. I am able to see the records in QGIS but not the geometries.

In my code, I take the shapely polygons read in from census shapefiles, compute properties and feed the polygons with the relevant attributes to fiona filewriter.

```
# schema for the file
myschema = {
'geometry':'Polygon',
'properties':{'is boundary':'int','id':'str', 'district':'int'}
}

with fiona.open(name,'w',crs=from_epsg(4326), driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=myschema) as output:
...
self.w.write({
                        'geometry':mapping(sg.asShape(self.subunit)),
                        'properties':{'is boundary':int(is_boundary), 'id':str(self.sid), 'district':0},
                        })
```

self.w is a reference to output after it's passed to an object and self.subunit is a pysal polygon geometry which I convert to shapely in order to write it to my shapefile. Has anyone had problems with this shapefile writing using fiona and know where my problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I recommend you to ask these kind of questions in the GIS stack: https://gis.stackexchange.com

Second: I can't comment so I answer here

Be sure that the output of

```
sg.asShape(self.subunit)
```

gives a proper geometry object. If you print it what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

The shapefile needs to be [explicitely closed](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#closing-files) (`outfile.close()`).

In principle opening the file with a `with` statement should take care of the closing, but since you mention writing it as a reference after having passed it to an object, this may be the issue anyway.